# Is there a good alternative URL parser in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I am using java.net.URL and it worked fine in my workstation until it get deployed in amazon elastic map-reduce, always gives me this error.
I am using openjdk1.7.0.

> Exception in thread "Thread-969" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent
>   Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file
>   javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet

```
        URL url = null;
    HashMap<String, Object> refererHash = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        url = new URL(referrer);
        String protocol = url.getProtocol();
        if(protocol != null){
            refererHash.put("protocol", protocol);
        }
        HashMap<String, String> params = parseParameters(url.getQuery());
        String path = url.getPath();
```

Does anyone encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with URL parsing at all.  It is actually a class loading problem which is (probably) caused by using a "stub" version of some JAR file.  Check your dependencies.  Specifically check the dependency that is providing the `HttpServlet` class.

Here's a blog posting that talks about this strange / unusual error.

- http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/